# Загрузка контента на JavaScript

Tags: jquery, javascript, html, php

Имеется шаблон в нем в `div` подгружается контент из другого файла методом .load
*Например*:

```
<head>
     <script src="jquery.1.8.2.php"></script>
     <script>
         function onLoad() {
             $('#content').load('file.php');
         }
     </script>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="#" onclick="onLoad()">Загрузить</a>
    <div id="content"></div>
</body>
```

Вот в чем собственно проблема. Контент загружается нормально. Но после загрузки на загруженный контент почему то не срабатывают `JavaScript` скрипты.

Например если в файле `file.php` есть стильный чекбокс на `JavaScript`, то после загрузки контента будет отоброжатся стандартный чекбокс без `JavaScript`.

*В чем может быть проблема ???*

Comment: А как скрипты file.php загружаются? Через windous.load ?

Comment: Файл file.php содержит только html.И он через метод .load загружается в #content очень даже хорошо. Но на этот html не действует `JS`. Например если в file.php есть метод .hide то для него нужна `JS` библиотека(которая включена в <head>) но она на загруженный файл не сработает

Нужна замена методу `.load` какая нибудь другая функция

Comment: Ну так запускайте ваши скрипты из file.php по собственному event, который будет срабатывать из главной страницы после загрузки file.php

Comment: пишите скрипт для ваших стильных чекбоксов прямо в file.php и оберните в функцию, которая будет выполнятся после полной загрузки DOM. Андрей Советкин сказал то же самое, я просто расшифровываю :)

Comment: Решили проблему? у меня такая же проблема у гостей сайта, а у залогиненных проблем нет.

Comment: Этому вопросу уже 5 лет )) А вообще надо использовать делегирование, и тогда не будет ни у кого проблем ))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

при каждой хагрузке контента нужно переопределять бинды.

т.е. если у вас есть код на js, который вешает обработчик на теги с классом data (к примеру) и он работает, а из файла file.php появляется еще какойто тэг с классом data, то на подгруженную фигню оно не будет реагировать и для этого нужно еще раз повесить обработчик на класс data

Comment: не понятна суть проблемы тогда.

Comment: что такие стильный чекбокс и что такое без javascript тогда?

Comment: Например в файле `file.php` есть `<input type="checkbox">` а в файле `index.php` (в который загружается `file.php` посредством `.load`) подключен `<script src="checkbox.ui.js">` с помощью этого скрипта стилизируется стандартный `checkbox`. Но проблема в том что этот `<script src="checkbox.ui.js">` не срабатывает, так как содержимое `file.php` не находится в `index.php` а подгружается методом `.load`

Comment: а, ну так я об этом и говорил... надо заново все функции на вешивать на вновьприбывших...